# Unsigned Long in LotusScript? How to turn off overflow detection on long?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

Context: I'm implementing a SHA-256 hashing to Lotusscript.

Hashing works on 32bits. LotusScript has only **signed** Long. When result are bigger than 2,147,483,647 we get **overflow**.

QUESTION: **how to turn off overflow detection** on Long?

If impossible, is there a working around? I was thinking at what *Richard Schwartz* has wroten in http://femkegoedhart.com/2012/02/05/lotusscript-timedifference-long-data-type-grrr/, how could I use NotesDateTime to help work around my problem?

Should I "forget this" but then how to hash in Lotusscript (ok I can think to use LS2J and use a standard java SHA 256)

Of course if you've got a LS implementation of SHA-256 it's also a good response :-)

Thank for your help, I feel a bit lost...

part of the code:

```
Dim T1 As Long
Dim h2 As Long 
Dim Sigma1 As Long
Dim K_t As Long

h2=1541459225
Sigma1 = 21895337
K_t=1116352408 

MsgBox String(32-Len(Bin$(h2)),"0")+Bin$(h2)+" " +"Bin$(h2)"+Chr$(13)+ _
String(32-Len(Bin$(Sigma1)),"0")+Bin$(Sigma1)+" " +"Bin$(Sigma1)"+Chr$(13)+ _
String(32-Len(Bin$(K_t)),"0")+Bin$(K_t)+" " +"Bin$(K_t)",,"DEBUG" 

T1 = h2 + Sigma1
MsgBox "T1 = " & T1 & " binary representation:" + String(32-Len(Bin$(T1)),"0")+  Bin$(T1)

T1 = h2 + Sigma1 + K_t  ' **this line cause overflow**
MsgBox "T1 = " & T1 & " binary representation:" + String(32-Len(Bin$(T1)),"0")+  Bin$(T1)
```

NB I based my implementation on the work of *Chris Veness*: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html

Comment: I haven't studied SHA-256, so I'm posting this as a comment instead of as an answer; and if SHA-256 is deliberately optimized for 32-bit unsigned operations then feel free to ignore this comment. IMHO, any crypto function in LotusScript (or similar languages) should probably be implemented using arrays of the Byte data type. Also, bear in mind that native strings in LotusScript are Unicode (UTF-16), so you have to be very careful -- particularly if you are expecting your hash to be validated by code that accepts string input as UTF-8.

Comment: Try to divide algorithm to smaller steps and convert partial results to fit variable limits.

Answer (score 2):

You can't turn off the overflow detection on a LONG in LotusScript. Also your sample above the BIN() function will attempt to convert to a long, so that rules out the use of DOUBLE.

The dateTime, object while it treats the number as LONG unsigned, it is probably a bit of hack to use.

Personally I'd recommend creating a small C DLL which does the work and passes it back as a string.

Alternatively create your code in Java as it doesn't have the same limitations that LS has.

Comment: what do you mean " so that rules out the use of DOUBLE" ?

Comment: using dateTime would definitly be an hack ... I admit it! I wouldn't  be happy to use such trick and stop terrified before transfering in prod...

Comment: The double will hold the value you want for you, but when you try to use BIN(value), if value is not an INTEGER or LONG, it will attempt to convert it to a LONG. It will fail at that point.

Answer (score 0):

As answered Simon O'Doherty, there is **no way to turn off the overflow detection on a LONG in LotusScript.**

I abandon the LS way... for now (maybe will I do an other attempt one day. Frantisek Kossuth, your right I need to take from the begining the variable limits... that the tricky part here)

Thanks for your help!

*Simon: I prefere to do LS2J than DLL!

I join the very simple class in java:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class SHA256 {
public String sha256(String message) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    String resu = A9Utility.bytesToHex(md1.digest(message.getBytes()));

    System.out.println("here SHA256: resu ="+resu);
    return resu;
}
}
```

for A9Utility.bytesToHex, I used the https://code.google.com/p/a9cipher/source/browse/src/cosc385final/A9Utility.java

so my call in LS is now:

```
UseLSX "*javacon"   
Use "SHA256"
[...]
Dim mySession As JavaSession
Dim myClass As JavaClass
Dim myObject As JavaObject
Set mySession = New JavaSession()

Set myClass = mySession.GetClass("SHA256")
Set myObject = myClass.CreateObject()

Dim resu As String
resu = myObject.sha256(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an COM component in LS and call it. There are a number of well developed and proven SHA-256 (and other hashes) COM components out there.

If you follow this route, you will need to 'handle' the return value as a string or some other binary encoding (base64?) as the result may (or may not) require unsigned longs to hold a raw value. Most of these components provide methods for doing this.

Bit 'old fashioned' for todays apps, but hey, you're using LS, so maybe that is not a concern.